# Trigger to insert values from another table - Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I did this to trigger when the temperature is higher or lower than the parameter set off an alarm. Ie automatically populates the fields of the table alarm.

Now I created a new row in the table alarms, the idRegisto which is foreign key, now I want that id be completed in accordance with the idRegisto other corresponding table.

Does anyone can help me please?

If you are not understanding the question I will try to clarify further.

Thank you.

------------TRIGGER-------------------

```
DELIMITER $$
create TRIGGER alerta
BEFORE INSERT ON registos
FOR EACH ROW
begin
Set @tempmax=0;
Set @tempmin=0;
Set @hummax=0;


select lim_inf_temp, lim_sup_temp into @tempmin, @tempmax from sensores  where idSensor=NEW.idSensor;


Set @maxidAlarme=0;
if (CAST(NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED)<@tempmin) then
SELECT MAX(idAlarme) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
SET @maxidAlarme=@maxidAlarme+1;
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"high-temperature");
INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) VALUES     (NEW.idSensor,@maxidAlarme,NOW());
end if; 


if (CAST(NEW.Temperatura AS UNSIGNED)>@tempmax) then
SELECT MAX(idAlarme) into @maxidAlarme FROM alarmes;
SET @maxidAlarme=@maxidAlarme+1;
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"lower temperature");
INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) VALUES (NEW.idSensor,@maxidAlarme,NOW());
end if; 
DELIMITER  ;
```

------------ER------------------------

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an "after insert trigger"

**AFTER** INSERT ON registos

And take the "New.IdRegistro" to use as foreign key when populating the alarmes table.

//EDIT:
using your code:

```
AFTER INSERT ON registos
FOR EACH ROW
begin
Set @tempmax=0;
Set @tempmin=0;
Set @hummax=0;
```

...

```
INSERT INTO alarmes(idAlarme,descricao_alarme,idRegistro) VALUES (@maxidAlarme,"lower temperature",New.IdRegistro);

INSERT INTO sensores_tem_alarmes(idSensor,idAlarme,dataAlarme) VALUES (NEW.idSensor,@maxidAlarme,NOW());
```

...

I assume here that IdRegistro is a primary key (that will be autogenarated by your application or via autoincrement) of the registro table.

Register->if value higher/lower threshold -> trigger alarm -> insert sensores_tem_alarmes

Comment: Thanks fpr reply. could you explain in a most practical way please?